# redis cluster continuously print log WSA_IO_PENDING

Tags: redis

When I start up all the redis-server of the redis cluster, all these servers continuously print logs like WSA_IO_PENDING clusterWriteDone

```
[9956] 03 Feb 18:17:25.044 # WSA_IO_PENDING writing to socket fd -------------------------------------------------------- 
[9956] 03 Feb 18:17:25.062 # clusterWriteDone written 2520 fd 15----------------------------------------------------------‌​--- 
[9956] 03 Feb 18:17:25.545 # WSA_IO_PENDING writing to socket fd -------------------------------------------------------- 
[9956] 03 Feb 18:17:25.568 # WSA_IO_PENDING writing to socket fd -------------------------------------------------------- –
```

Comment: Seeing the same in Windows event log, logging set to "notice". However Redis is working correctly, just a pain to filter logs :(

Comment: @rob, what is the sample config you are using for the cluster?

Comment: @TarunLalwani here is a pastebin of the redis.windows-service.conf with all the lines starting with # removed
https://pastebin.com/wJK5pj73
The only action I took after installing was to uncomment `#cluster-enabled yes
#cluster-config-file nodes-6379.conf
#cluster-node-timeout 15000`

Comment: @rob, Can you also provide a sample log so time intervals can be looked into ?

Comment: it appears to be a couple of log entries every second. here is the last 200 entries from the redis.log file. that mirrors the windows event log.https://pastebin.com/BwMgXgsM
Since installing he service 2017/10/09 there are 15,402,540 lines at almost 1gb in the log file.

Comment: There's an open issue for that, but it seems to be abandoned: https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues/3793

Comment: that will teach me for using Windows. It was supposed to be a quick win not to have to stand up additional Linux VMs. Where I am, getting new VMs can take ages, red tape etc.

Comment: @karliwson looks like technically you are correct. I may not like it but if you 
 create that as an answer the bounty is yours.

Comment: @rob ok, it's done.

Comment: That issue was opened on the main Redis repository. I don't think you'll find much help there because this problem is related to the [Windows Redis Fork](https://github.com/MicrosoftArchive/redis) maintained by Microsoft. The error you see is returned *by the OS* to programs using the Windows Sockets API (Winsock) used by Redis on Windows. `WSA_IO_PENDING` does not indicate an error. It's a nuance of Winsock returned (in the same way as an error) to indicate to the program the state of an operation, so Redis must be logging any code returned as non-zero. It may indicate a busy server/network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to specifically turn those "warnings" off in 3.2.x port of Redis for Windows as the logging statements use highest `LL_WARNING` level. This issue has been reported in my fork of that unmaintained MSOpenTech's repo (which I updated to Redis 4.0.2) and has been fixed by decreasing that level to `LL_DEBUG`. More details: https://github.com/tporadowski/redis/issues/14

This change will be included in the next release (4.0.2.3) or you can get the latest source code and build it for yourself.

Current releases can be found here: https://github.com/tporadowski/redis/releases

Answer (score 2):

An issue was open in the official redis repo 10 months ago about that problem. Unfortunately it seems to be abandoned, and it hasn't been solved yet:

[Redis cluster print "WSA_IO_PENDING writing to socket..." continuously, does it matter?](https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues/3793)

However, that issue may not be related to redis itself, but to the Windows Sockets API, as pointed out by  Cy Rossignol in the comments. It's the winsock API that returns that status to the application, [as seen in the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668(v=vs.85).aspx):

> **WSA_IO_PENDING (997)**
>
> Overlapped operations will complete later.
>
> The application has
>   initiated an overlapped operation that cannot be completed
>   immediately. A completion indication will be given later when the
>   operation has been completed. Note that this error is returned by the
>   operating system, so the error number may change in future releases of
>   Windows.

Maybe it didn't get much attention because it's not a bug, although it's indeed an inconvenience that floods the system logs. In that case, you may not get help there.

Seems like there's no temporary fix. The [Windows Redis fork](https://github.com/MicrosoftArchive/redis) is archived and I don't know if you could get any help there either.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go on this location `C:\Program Files\Redis`
2. Open file `redis.windows-service.conf` in Notepad.

You will find a section like below:

```
# Specify the server verbosity level.
# This can be one of:
# debug (a lot of information, useful for development/testing)
# verbose (many rarely useful info, but not a mess like the debug level)
# notice (moderately verbose, what you want in production probably)
# warning (only very important / critical messages are logged)
loglevel notice

# Specify the log file name. Also 'stdout' can be used to force
# Redis to log on the standard output.
logfile "Logs/redis_log.txt"
```

Here, you can change the value of `loglevel` as per your requirement. I think changing it to `warning` will solve this issue because it will log only essential errors.

Comment: As Tomasz pointed out in his answer, Microsoft's Redis fork [records the messages in question at the "warning" level](https://github.com/MicrosoftArchive/redis/blob/7fe877251355c6e9ec627b6a6077449bbb3f08a6/src/cluster.c#L2045) so changing the logging verbosity probably won't hide the unwanted entries.