# Overly verbose logging in Redis Cluster

Tags: windows, redis

I have a Redis Cluster setup with the following redis.conf:

```
bind 127.0.0.1
bind 10.0.0.20

port 7000
cluster-enabled yes
cluster-config-file nodes.7000.conf
cluster-node-timeout 15000
appendonly yes
appendfilename "appendonly.7000.aof"

timeout 0
tcp-keepalive 60

databases 1
stop-writes-on-bgsave-error no

loglevel warning
logfile "serverlog.7000.txt"
```

Each machine in the cluster has 2 instances of Redis running; one on Port 7000, one on Port 7001.

Even though my loglevel is `warning`, I'm still getting several log statements every second.  `serverlog.7000.txt` looks something like this:

```
[1112] 09 Apr 06:44:28.623 # WSA_IO_PENDING writing to socket fd 14
[1112] 09 Apr 06:44:28.623 # clusterWriteDone written 2520 fd 14
[1112] 09 Apr 06:44:28.842 # WSA_IO_PENDING writing to socket fd 27
[1112] 09 Apr 06:44:28.842 # clusterWriteDone written 2520 fd 27
[1112] 09 Apr 06:44:28.936 # WSA_IO_PENDING writing to socket fd 23
[1112] 09 Apr 06:44:28.936 # clusterWriteDone written 2520 fd 23
[1112] 09 Apr 06:44:29.717 # WSA_IO_PENDING writing to socket fd 17
[1112] 09 Apr 06:44:29.717 # clusterWriteDone written 2520 fd 17
[1112] 09 Apr 06:44:29.748 # WSA_IO_PENDING writing to socket fd 21
[1112] 09 Apr 06:44:29.748 # clusterWriteDone written 2520 fd 21
[1112] 09 Apr 06:44:30.607 # WSA_IO_PENDING writing to socket fd 10
[1112] 09 Apr 06:44:30.607 # clusterWriteDone written 2520 fd 10
[1112] 09 Apr 06:44:30.811 # WSA_IO_PENDING writing to socket fd 11
[1112] 09 Apr 06:44:30.811 # clusterWriteDone written 2520 fd 11
[1112] 09 Apr 06:44:31.795 # WSA_IO_PENDING writing to socket fd 13
[1112] 09 Apr 06:44:31.795 # clusterWriteDone written 2520 fd 13
[1112] 09 Apr 06:44:31.904 # WSA_IO_PENDING writing to socket fd 12
[1112] 09 Apr 06:44:31.904 # clusterWriteDone written 2416 fd 12
[1112] 09 Apr 06:44:32.217 # WSA_IO_PENDING writing to socket fd 23
[1112] 09 Apr 06:44:32.217 # clusterWriteDone written 2520 fd 23
[1112] 09 Apr 06:44:32.779 # WSA_IO_PENDING writing to socket fd 16
[1112] 09 Apr 06:44:32.779 # clusterWriteDone written 2520 fd 16
[1112] 09 Apr 06:44:32.858 # WSA_IO_PENDING writing to socket fd 29
[1112] 09 Apr 06:44:32.858 # clusterWriteDone written 2520 fd 29
[1112] 09 Apr 06:44:32.998 # WSA_IO_PENDING writing to socket fd 11
[1112] 09 Apr 06:44:32.998 # clusterWriteDone written 2520 fd 11
[1112] 09 Apr 06:44:34.092 # WSA_IO_PENDING writing to socket fd 17
[1112] 09 Apr 06:44:34.092 # clusterWriteDone written 2520 fd 17
[1112] 09 Apr 06:44:35.186 # WSA_IO_PENDING writing to socket fd 14
[1112] 09 Apr 06:44:35.186 # clusterWriteDone written 2520 fd 14
[1112] 09 Apr 06:44:35.186 # WSA_IO_PENDING writing to socket fd 117
[1112] 09 Apr 06:44:35.186 # clusterWriteDone written 2416 fd 117
[1112] 09 Apr 06:44:35.404 # WSA_IO_PENDING writing to socket fd 27
[1112] 09 Apr 06:44:35.404 # clusterWriteDone written 2520 fd 27
[1112] 09 Apr 06:44:35.483 # WSA_IO_PENDING writing to socket fd 19
[1112] 09 Apr 06:44:35.483 # clusterWriteDone written 2520 fd 19
[1112] 09 Apr 06:44:36.076 # WSA_IO_PENDING writing to socket fd 10
[1112] 09 Apr 06:44:36.076 # clusterWriteDone written 2520 fd 10
[1112] 09 Apr 06:44:36.279 # WSA_IO_PENDING writing to socket fd 13
[1112] 09 Apr 06:44:36.279 # clusterWriteDone written 2520 fd 13
[1112] 09 Apr 06:44:37.295 # WSA_IO_PENDING writing to socket fd 21
[1112] 09 Apr 06:44:37.295 # clusterWriteDone written 2520 fd 21
[1112] 09 Apr 06:44:37.373 # WSA_IO_PENDING writing to socket fd 12
[1112] 09 Apr 06:44:37.373 # clusterWriteDone written 2520 fd 12
[1112] 09 Apr 06:44:37.686 # WSA_IO_PENDING writing to socket fd 23
[1112] 09 Apr 06:44:37.686 # clusterWriteDone written 2520 fd 23
```

This is creating a couple hundred megs of log data every day which is a bit tough to come through and also requires us to watch disk space more carefully.  This log events don't really seem like *warnings* to me.  Is there any way to turn them off or fix the issue?  I've tried all the other documented loglevels, but nothing seems to make these go away.

I'm using Redis 3.2.100 on Windows 2012.

**Update:** I noticed these are also completely flooding the Windows Event Log as well.

Comment: Found [dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42021901/redis-cluster-continuosly-print-log-wsa-io-pending) of my own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to specifically turn those "warnings" off in 3.2.100 as the logging statements use highest `LL_WARNING` level. This issue has been reported in my fork of that unmaintained MSOpenTech's repo (which I updated to Redis 4.0.2) and has been fixed by decreasing that level to `LL_DEBUG`. More details: https://github.com/tporadowski/redis/issues/14

This change will be included in the next release (4.0.2.3) or you can get the latest source code and build it for yourself.

Current releases can be found here: https://github.com/tporadowski/redis/releases